# Why do people frequently change tunes toward the end of Lecha Dodi?

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, song-poetry, minhag

Frequently, perhaps even most of the time, I've noticed that the chazan (prayer leader) for [Kabalat Shabbat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish%5Fservices#Friday%5Fnight) switches tunes for the last four verses of [Lecha Dodi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lekhah%5FDodi). Is there any reason for this, or are people just doing it because other people do it?

Comment: I don;t think every little detail of Jewish practice has to have a deep reason. Its clearly just for variety.

Comment: @ArielK - I don't mean to offend or be judgmental, but I once heard that someone who denies *Sod* is like a *Pered* (donkey?), because the exegetical methods of *Torah* are compared to a *Pardes* (orchard), which includes the letter *Samekh*.  *Rabbi Yishmael Omer* (at the end of Korbanot in Tefillat Shacharit) teaches the 13 methods of exegesis for *Drash*.  Saying that there is no *Sod* is kind of like saying that a *Kal va-Chomer* is invalid.  I just want to say that secrets are part of Jewish tradition.  Hanistarot Lashem Elokeinu Vhaniglot Lanu Ulivaneinu Ad Olam. Cf. http://jewi.sh/11ed3

Comment: @AdamMosheh, I think that ArielK's point is that not everything you see Jews doing is connected to a point of Sod (or Peshat, for that matter), not that there's no such thing as Sod.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - But it makes sense to me that everything has Sod connected to it.  However, "*Hanistarot Lashem Elokeinu*," and often times verbalization of the Sod is wrong.  But to say that there is no Sod is incorrect because there is Sod even if it isn't verbalized.

Comment: @AdamMosheh No offense at being compared to a donkey, the Torah compares Yissachar himself to one (though pered is actually a mule, which might be a less complimentary animal). However, according to your method, someone who denies remez would be a Prize (or Persia), which doesn't seem that bad. (Though that doesn't mean I'm against all remez either!)

Comment: though wfb found the source. theres a chida quoted in bnei yissachar which says ur a pered for no sod, and tipesh if just peshat. i still think one could claim to be a prize though...

Comment: @ArielK I think I agree with the OP. This custom is far too wide-spread, extending through the dozens of tunes I've heard to that piyut. While it is _possible_ that there is no deeper reason, dismissing it as "clearly" just for variety without looking around seems like the wrong approach.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to R' Ari Enkin, [writing on Hirhurim:](http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2010/01/lecha-dodichanging-tune.html)

> Although there is a widespread custom to change the tune during Lecha Dodi when reaching the stanza of "Lo Tevoshi", it is actually quite unclear where this custom derives from. Some sources even suggest that it is baseless and evolved without reason.

I recommend that you read the whole piece and see what he's uncovered. Indeed, there doesn't seem to be a good reason to change tunes then. If anything, it might make sense to change tunes one verse earlier.

Comment: If your tune scheme involves one verse low, one verse high, it might not work to switch one verse earlier.  But that's technical, not religious.

Comment: Maybe because people sometimes get tired of singing the same thing for so long so they change the tune to change it up a bit and give the singers some new life.

Answer (score 28):

There is an old minhag Frankfurt to sing the first part of Lekha Dodi, which refers to exile, to a slow tune, and then switching to a happier nigun when switching to *nechamah* (consolation) about the future redemption at *His'oreri*. However, in that *minhag*, they switched back to the original tune for the last verse, *Bo'i Beshalom*, to link it back to the opening verses that refer to Shabbos, not redemption. (See Liqrat Kallah pg 147.)

Comment: But doesn't Hisoreri also refer to the redemption? (And arguably Hisna'ari does too.)

Comment: Indeed, Alex, I believe the minhag Frankfurt is to switch tunes at the Hisoriri stanza. For some listening examples which have the characteristic change of tune, with a possible reprise of the initial tune at the end, go to http://kayj.org/nusach/Shabbos-Kabbolas_Shabbos.html

Comment: @Alex: According to the article quoted in the answer below, the custom was to change at Hisoreri, not at Lo Seivoshi. That article also quotes the same Likrat Kallah, but I wasn't able to find it online to look it up. In the article, it says that the first 4 represent exile and the 2nd 4 redemption, but also says that the first 4 spell out Shlomo, which reminds us of Moshiach (seems a bit contradictory). It would be nice to read it inside and see what it says: http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2010/01/lecha-dodichanging-tune.html

Comment: Micha, it can't be that old a minhag. The Kehillah of Frankfurt did not adopt Kabbalat Shabbat until after R' Hirsch became the mora d'atra

Comment: Rabbi Micha why do they switch back to the original tune for the last verse, it refers to Shabbos, not exile?

Comment: So do the first two verses. before we discuss exile: Shamor veZakhor and Liqras Shabbos. Perhaps it's just to link back to the original theme.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I think I meant "old" as opposed to the contemporary practices of most descendants of Jews with minhag Frankfurt. But 4 years later, who knows?

Comment: Who knows (15) ?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt, maybe one of those guys hanging out singing on the stairs?

Answer (score 4):

I have often been quite thankful for this minhag (although I don't know the source). There are many times when the chazan (prayer leader) will choose a tune which is (a) painfully slow or unmelodic, or (b) nobody in the congregation knows, leaving him to sing alone.
The tradition of switching tunes halfway through provides an instituted opportunity to cut the bad tune off and try again.

This is especially helpful for lecha dodi where there is such a large number of tunes that exist.

Comment: What hapens when the Chazan goes from bad to worse?

Comment: All hope is lost, and you have to wait until next Kabalat Shabbat to get another chance.

Hopefully the Chazan will be wise enough to pick an old classic as his "switch-to" tune so as to minimize this possibility.

Comment: This sounds like an opinion rather than an answer to the question. A good chazzan should have a sense of the congregation, and pick tunes that they know. A regular paid chazzan knows. A *shaliach tzibbur* (i.e., a random picked congregant) can sense if something is wrong after about 1 verse. There's nothing wrong with using the same tune for the whole thing.

Comment: Yep, my "answer" should likely have been (at most) a comment on the original question instead. 
I'll add this for my to-do list once I get my time machine working.

Answer (score 2):

Variety is the spice of life.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: @DanF, it's definitely an answer. It might not be very satisfying, I'll admit.

Comment: What if you abhor spicy stuff?

Comment: Some answers are here to spice things up.