# Does anyone know what siddur the Minchas Elazar, z"l, used?

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, historical-figures, chassidic-rebbe

I was wondering if anyone knows what specific siddur the Minchas Elazar, z"l, davened from?  Also, where to find it today.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56001/759

Comment: I’m not sure if this is relevant, but his Wikipedia bio in Hebrew lists at the end of the section dealing with his early life that he was given a version of the Ari z”l siddur called Siddur Chemdat Yisrael that was hand written by Rabbi Shmuel Vital, son of Rabbi Chaim Vital by the Shinover Rav & told to publish it. It says he did this and added his own introduction to the siddur.

Comment: The link from DoubleAA also mentions in the photo from the Munkatcher Shul in Canada the same siddur (Siddur Chemdat Yisrael). Here is a link to that siddur which also includes the introduction from the Minchat Elazar. http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53884&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=