# Intentionally mispronouncing lashon hakodesh in religious services

Tags: halacha, tefilla, pronunciation

With regard to written texts, a Torah is invalidated if the same character is written for what should be distinct letters (e.g. כ and ב). However, with regard to the spoken language and people who are unable to pronounce a letter correctly, the Midrash ([Shir HaShirim Rabba parsha 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42625&st=&pgnum=26), on [Shir HaShirim 2:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3002.htm#4) [hattip @DoubleAA]) interprets the verse "ודגלו עלי אהבה" to say that G-d counts their intent, not their spoken words (the case used in the *derash* is the extreme example where one read "ואהבת" ["and thou shall love"] as "ואיבת" ["and thou shall hate"]).

If, however, someone is able to pronounce the sounds correctly but was taught by their teachers the wrong pronunciation, and never bothered updating his pronunciation even after finding out the error, is his mispronunciation halachically valid (e.g. for kriyat shema, parshat amalek, tefilla, etc.)?

Comment: See *Bava Basra* 21[a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=21&format=text)-[b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=21b&format=text), for a story involving mispronouncing *parshas 'Amalek*.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18529/759 and all the questions linked therein

Comment: Are you specifically asking concerning mispronouncing that alters the meaning of the word? Otherwise, your scenario reflects similarity to regional accents. For example, theword "Torah" is  technically pronounced TOE-RAH or TOE-RA but some communities say TA--RA and TOY-RAW. In addition, Ashkenazim and Sephardim place word stress  differently; either on the medial or final sound.   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Hebrew_phonology

Comment: seems like a biased question. There are many different accents but who can rightfully claim theirs is the only correct one and all others are wrong?

Comment: @Dude The people who base their pronunciation on mountains of historical and linguistic evidence. In any event, the question doesn't specify which would be considered the only correct one, so is unbiased to any side, and is asking theoretically. There could always be application in unusual Baal Teshuva cases or post-medical treatments or something.

Comment: " and never bothered updating his pronunciation even after finding out the error, " - its hard to update your pronunciation once you've been using a particular one for a few months or even years.

Comment: [Sefer Chasidim 18](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41862&st=&pgnum=60) ואחרי שאינו יודע לדבר כענין מעלה עליו כאלו אומר יפה...על זה נאמר ודגלו עלי אהבה מעילתו עלי אהבה

Comment: @DoubleAA re "There could always be application in unusual Baal Teshuva cases"  - I believe I saw years ago a mishna in Horayos (?) discussed by the Raavad and/or Gr"a? cited in the Artscroll gemara, about accurately presenting the language of one's teachers when they (Shmaya and Avtalyon?) were gerim and mispronounced the words.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47352&st=&pgnum=54

Comment: @DoubleAA sounds more like an answer...

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22224&st=&pgnum=72

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=63&format=pdf http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=22b&format=pdf

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19962&st=&pgnum=499