# What is the history behind the Chassidishe havarah?

Tags: history, chasidut-hasidism, pronunciation

I know this can be considered "unspecific," as there are many Chassidus with many havaros (e.g. Karlin Stolin, which IINM is very similar to a Litvish havarah, vs e.g. Belz, which has a more "traditional" Chassidishe havarah), contingent on region or community of origin of a given sect. I am just attempting to speak in generalities.

How did the Chassidishe havarah come to be? For example, there seems to be consensus on a few sounds, such as the shuruk, as an "oo" sound, which a number of Chassidus pronounce as "ee." Seeing as the genesis of Chassidus (by its modern definition, again generally speaking) can be traced back to the 18th century with the Baal Shem Tov, I'm wondering if the havarah traces back to a similarly recent time, and what the history is behind its development.

Comment: From what I've heard, it's more about regional differences that predate chassidus.

Comment: Compare with https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yiddish_dialects (specifically Southern (Polish and Ukrainian) Yiddish pronunciation)

Comment: Is this relevant : https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18529/chassidic-rebbes-dont-use-hebrew-grammar ?

Comment: There's a whole bunch of relevant content on the regional differences in the following: https://www.dovidkatz.net/ and
https://www.dovidkatz.net/WebAtlas/AtlasSamples.htm and
http://dovidkatz.net/dovid/dovid_linguistics.htm